# Обновление таблицы

Tags: sql, postgresql

Существует таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE "DATA" 
(
date timestamp without time zone, 
array_values int[]
);
```

В ней находятся данные:

```
INSERT INTO "DATA" (date, array_values )
VALUES ('2017-01-19 00:00:00',ARRAY[1,2,3]);

INSERT INTO "DATA" (date, array_values )
VALUES ('2017-01-19 00:00:00',ARRAY[4,5,6]);

INSERT INTO "DATA" (date, array_values )
VALUES ('2017-01-19 00:00:00',ARRAY[7,8]);

INSERT INTO "DATA" (date, array_values )
VALUES ('2017-01-19 01:01:01',ARRAY[100,102]);

INSERT INTO "DATA" (date, array_values )
VALUES ('2017-01-19 01:01:01',ARRAY[103,104,105,106]);
```

Как произвести обновление таблицы, что бы массивы с одинаковыми датами были объединены в один?

> "2017-01-19 00:00:00" | {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
>
> "2017-01-19 01:01:01" | {101,102,103,104,105,106}

Comment: Т.е. вам надо часть строк удалить и что бы у оставшихся была полная сумма массивов по дате ?

Comment: Да, часть строк удалить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаг первый - переформатировать данные. Для этого можно распаковать массив unnset'ом и собрать через array_agg при группировке:

```
select date, array_agg(av) 
    from "DATA" 
    cross join unnest(array_values) av 
group by 1;
```

Шаг второй, внести изменения в табличку. Проще всего скопировать всё в отдельную табличку, сделать truncate и скопировать данные обратно:

```
create temporary table data_tmp_agg
select date, array_agg(av) as array_values
    from "DATA" 
    cross join unnest(array_values) av 
group by 1;

truncate table "DATA";

insert into "DATA" (date, array_values ) select date, array_values from data_tmp_agg;
```

Или, что наверное будет лучше, сделать:

```
ALTER TABLE "DATA" RENAME TO old_data;

create table "DATA" ...

insert into "DATA" (date, array_values ) 
select date, array_agg(av) as array_values
    from old_data 
    cross join unnest(array_values) av 
group by 1;
```

Т.е. переименовать табличку.

Можно собрать один CTE, которым поселектить нужные данные, обновить одни строки, удалить остальные дубликаты. А вариант с пересозданием таблички зато не потребует вакуума, и дисковое место системе сразу будет возвращено вместо оставления мёртвых строк.

PS: не забудьте после массового изменения сделать analyze.

Answer (score 1):

Одним запросом:

```
WITH DEL as(
  delete from "DATA"
   where ctid in(
     select ctid from (
       select ctid, row_number() over(partition by date) rn
         from "DATA"
      ) A where rn>1
   )
  returning date, array_values
)
update "DATA" U set array_values=U.array_values || D.arr::integer[]
  from (
   select date, string_to_array(string_agg(array_to_string(array_values,','),','),',') arr
     from DEL
    group by date
  ) D
 where U.date=D.date
```

Сначала происходит удаление лишних строк, возвращающее удаленные данные. После происходит дозапись значений массивов из удаленных строк в оставшиеся.